# How to automate the maximize the window of an Electron application using Selenium

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

Currently I am performing End to end testing of an application developed using electron framework. I am able to open the application using selenium and also able to interact wit h the form controls etc. When I open the application it opens in a minimized mode and I want to maximize it by performing the keystrokes **ALT + Space + X** The following is my code,it executes with out any errors but does not maximize the window.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void TestDispneseLogin()
        {           
            ChromeOptions chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
            chromeOptions.BinaryLocation = @"C:\CorumDispense-win32-x64\CorumDispense.exe";
            chromeOptions.AddArgument("start-maximized");
            DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capability.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "Chrome");
            capability.SetCapability("chromeOptions", chromeOptions);
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(chromeOptions);                           
            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            //maximize the window                
            Actions keyAction = new Actions(driver);
            keyAction.SendKeys(Keys.Alt);
            keyAction.SendKeys(Keys.Space);
            keyAction.SendKeys(Convert.ToString('\u0078'));
            keyAction.Build().Perform(); 

            //input the text into the patient text box          
            driver.FindElement(By.Id("patient")).SendKeys("bharat");
        }
```

I have also tried the option

```
keyAction.KeyDown(Keys.Alt).KeyDown(Keys.Space).SendKeys(Convert.ToString('\u0078')).Perform();
```

But it fails and gives me the following error

```
Test Name:  TestDispneseLogin
Test FullName:  LightHouseTestScenarios.TestScenarios.ElectronTest.TestDispneseLogin
Test Source:    C:\Automation\SeleniumProjects\Lighthouse\LightHouseTestScenarios\TestScenarios\ElectronTest.cs : line 83
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:05.1098462

Result StackTrace:  
at OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Internal.SingleKeyAction..ctor(IKeyboard keyboard, IMouse mouse, ILocatable actionTarget, String key)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions.KeyDown(IWebElement element, String theKey)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Interactions.Actions.KeyDown(String theKey)
   at LightHouseTestScenarios.TestScenarios.ElectronTest.TestDispneseLogin() in C:\Automation\SeleniumProjects\Lighthouse\LightHouseTestScenarios\TestScenarios\ElectronTest.cs:line 99
Result Message: 
Test method LightHouseTestScenarios.TestScenarios.ElectronTest.TestDispneseLogin threw exception: 
System.ArgumentException: key must be a modifier key (Keys.Shift, Keys.Control, or Keys.Alt)
Parameter name: key
```

I have also tried the below but with no success

```
keyAction.SendKeys(Keys.Alt + Keys.Space + Convert.ToString('\u0078')).Perform();
```

and also this option

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

Can some one help me solving this issue,thanks in advance.
cheers,
bharadwaj.

Answer (score 1):

When you need using electron features, the easy way to do it is working with the executeScript method.

instead:

```
driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();
```

replace with:

```
driver.executeScript("require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().maximize();");
```

Answer (score 1):

For python-selenium implementation, following worked for Electron:

```
self.session.execute_script('window.moveTo(0, 0);window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);')
```

It does not exactly maximize the window but sets the window size equal to screen size. Might not work for all types of applications.

Answer (score 0):

try this code.. Its working for me...

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("require('electron').remote.BrowserWindow.getFocusedWindow().maximize();");
```